# Google Drive & Service Account Storage Limit/Quota

Tags: google-drive-api

for my Google App Engine application I would like to use the Service Account's own Google Drive, i.e. I do not wish to create a "regular" gmail account and grant privileges to my Service Account, nor I want to share files with anyone else, I just wish to use the Drive as a "internal filesystem" for the application, accessed by the application only.

My questions:

1) is such service still provided, i.e. are Service Accounts granted to use their own private Drive, or am I forced to use the "new" Google Cloud Storage?

2) where can I find any relevant & updated information regarding the storage quota for such Drive & possible options for expanding it? I browsed many forums, but all posts I found (including on SO) contains dead links and/or states various information ("I think its 5 GB", "I believe its 15 GB" etc.)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can unravel the mystery :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Drive resource [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) and find all the information related to your Drive.

If you make the call from your service account, you can know what is the total amount of available space returned in the parameter `quotaBytesTotal` for that account.

I just checked and for me it was 15 GB, so that's likely the same available space you will get.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the hint, I completely missed that api, so I guess "rtfm" ;-) Although I still have not found an "official" statement Service Accounts quotas cant be increased, I will assume thats still the case and will just use an ordinary "user account" for the storage. Thanks for the help! (btw its indeed showing me roughly 15 GB of space)